# Opencart Colorbox AUTO height and width?

Tags: height, width, opencart, colorbox

i tried everything, but i cant figure out how to do that, that when i press 'next' photo,  and size of the hole popup changes with photo size. Like this : http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ elastic transition example. I tried do maxWidth and maxHeight 100% and upload this new version of colorbox files to the server... style a little bit changes, but main thing, resposive auto width and height didnt. Maybe i did something wrong, but i almost finished my page and have one problem left.

I believe in Stackoverflow now :)

Comment: I do not understand You at all. So does it now change the sizes and You do not want it to do that or it doesn't and You want it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure, that `scalePhotos` is not set to `false`. Secondly, `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` must be set with absolute values (pixels), not percentage. Percentage value is a way to get colorbox window with responsive dimensions. As I understand, you need "per contra" behavior, when colorbox's window does not change its size after new image is loaded from current set. So, you should use absolute values for `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`. For example:

```
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    scalePhotos: true, //'true' by default BTW
    maxWidth: '600px',
    maxHeight: '600px'
});
```